# How to upgrade Kernel from 2.6 to latest?

Tags: debian, kernel, upgrade

I am currently running Debian 8.2 (I know this is for Ubuntu questions but I do believe the process is similar)

And I can't seem to be able to upgrade my Kernel. The current version is: `2.6.32-308.el5.028stab099.3`

and I would like to upgrade to the latest stable kernel. Using `apt-get` to install linux images does not seem to do anything.

```
root@Moonraise:~# sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-4-586 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
linux-image-3.16.0-4-586 is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 70 not upgraded
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Output for `uname -a` and `lsb_release`

```
root@Moonraise:~# uname -a Linux Moonraise 2.6.32-308.el5.028stab099.3 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 15:56:00 MSK 2012 i686 GNU/Linux 
root@Moonraise:~# lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Debian Description: Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (n/a) Release: 8.2 Codename: n/a
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to install a newer linux-image?

Comment: There isn't a copy of this question on U&L, but the following from serverfault might apply: http://serverfault.com/questions/409934/kernel-will-not-upgrade-after-installing-linux-image-on-debian

Comment: Since I am running on a VPS by a hosting company. I would find it understandable that I would not be able to upgrade the kernel as I am guessing that I am limited by the VM.

Comment: `root@Moonraise:~# sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-4-586
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-3.16.0-4-586 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 70 not upgraded`

Is what I get when trying to install linux. Unfortunately I do not remember what it said the first time around...

Comment: You're probably running inside a container, so the running kernel is the host kernel, regardless of the kernel you install. You may want to ask your provider if they plan on upgrading one day!

Comment: I copied the apt-get output to the question body for clarity. Have you checked your boot-loader config, does it have anything for 3.16? If it does, you'd just need to select it as the default or manually change the loaded kernel at boot. If there doesn't seem to be anything about the new kernel, please do post the output of `ls -la /boot` and the bootloader config file.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel

> Make sure you read everything it tells you during the installation,
>   **especially about initrd image**. If you use an unusual boot loader, you
>   might need to reconfigure after installing the kernel image - don't
>   forget to tell it to use appropriate initrd image for the kernel in
>   this case (PackageManagement page has details about listing contents
>   of a package).

You clearly did download the newer kernel image but, obviously, it's not being called by your boot loader.

If you have access to the configuration of your boot loader, make sure the correct image is called.

More likely, however, you are running a system in a container, so only the host system administrator can change the kernel for you.